# Java: suppress warning "X is marked unstable"

Tags: java, warnings, guava, suppress-warnings

I am using the `com.google.common.net.MediaType` class from the [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library and it is marked as `@Beta`. I'd like to suppress warnings that this is marked as unstable.

What's the `@SuppressWarnings` key do I need to use?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use `@SuppressWarnings("UnstableApiUsage")` to suppress those warnings.

Comment: Thanks, this works for the usages of the `MediaType` but I am still getting a warning on the `import` statement at the top of the file. How do I ignore that?

Comment: @Kousha I'm not aware of a way to do that, sorry.

Comment: Just use the fully qualified path when you use MediaType (e.g. com.google.common.net.MediaType). This way you don't need the import statement and the single @SuppressWarnings statement will be enough.

Comment: @Mureinik - Thanks for the answer, can you describe how you figured this out?